# $stmt is boolean after $conn->prepare($sql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a PHP page, where I use mysqli.

I make two prepared statement SQL queries.

My problem is, that at the second query, `$conn->prepare($sql)` returns a boolean.

Second query:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `games` = ? WHERE `id` = ?
```

Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT games, username, displayname FROM users WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$result = $stmt->execute();

if ($result === FALSE){
    printErrorPage("Something went wrong: " . $conn->error);
    die();
}

$stmt->bind_result($json, $username, $displayname);
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows == 1){
    $stmt->fetch();
    var_dump($json);
    $games = json_decode($json);
    var_dump($games);
    $games_new = apiUpdate($games);
    if ($games_new != $games){
        $json_new = json_encode($games_new);

        $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `games` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("si", json_encode($games_new), $id);
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        if ($result !== TRUE){
            printErrorPage("Something went wrong: " . $conn->error);
            die();
        }
    }
    display($username, $displayname, $games_new);
} else {
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 0){
        header("Location: http://moger.net/gameboard/");
    } else {
        //absolute mindfuck
    }
    die();
}
```

*NOTE:* I think that `$conn->prepare($sql)` returns FALSE when the SQL syntax is incorrect, but I tested it on [this syntax tester](https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/) (with the prepared statement ?s replaced) and it said it's ok.

**EDIT:** The question got closed, so I'm going to put the answer here:
The UPDATE command wasn't allowed for the user I was using.

Comment: Check for [errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after your prepare statements.

Comment: from the doc : `mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @aynber The fatal error occurs when running $stmt->bind_param(...); because of $stmt being a boolean.

Comment: That's why you check for errors between your prepare and bind_param.

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ I tested the SQL query with a syntax tester, and it was correct.

Comment: as aynber said, check the errors from php using the `mysqli_error` and not with an external syntax tester...

Comment: never mind the syntax tester, you need to run it off your own server and check for errors there. Edit: Seems I've repeated the above comment that I didn't see while I was typing this out. Syntax testers have no idea as to what your db/variables/etc. are.

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ $conn->error is an empty string.

Comment: and what is returned by `$conn->connect_error` ?

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ Null.

Comment: have you activated the error reporting and display_errors in PHP ?

Comment: Whatever. All we can help with is to show you how to get the actual error from your server. To get it is your task, we can do very little here

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ no. How?

Comment: Check the question linked to this one